# Using chartboost callbacks/rewards (stuck midway)?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, chartboost

I'm trying to use chartboost callbacks to reward players for interstitial installs. So far I've managed to receive/process and store callbacks on my server after every install, however I do not know how to go beyond this (ie how to reward the player after an install has been registered), and i cant seem to find any documentation for this.
I was thinking of recontacting the server when the app restarts to compare chartboost user ids and check for registered installs(if this is the best way), but am unsure of how to get the chartboost userid from the app again directly in code..(outside of using callbacks)

I'm currently developing in unity3d for ios/android and am using chartboost's official sdk. Is this the best way of going about things^ ?. Any advice would be much appreciated.